# Magnetic field intensity

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

why is it $B/μ$ in the formula? and why do we define magnetization vector J as algebraic sum of magnetization currents I' enveloped by the contour

Comment: Are you aware that in Gaussian units there is no $\mu_0$? This makes clear that it has no physical significance but is merely an artifact of SI units.

Comment: but how is this formula derived??

Comment: Who on Earth would use $J$ for magnetization. Magnetization is $M$ and current density is $J$.

Comment: *enveloped by the contour* What contour?

Comment: The usual definition of [magnetization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization) is as the volume density of magnetic dipole moments.